# Wildcards Into Regular Expressions for Time

Tags: regex, outlook, wildcard

So I have been having trouble finding the correct syntax for capturing specific types of strings in word. I have figured out the regular expressions but the symbols are different in Outlook/Word and it seems like the `*` is not functioning the way I want. Can anyone assist with the wildcard version for the following expressions? And is it possible to use RegEx search in Outlook/Word vía VBA instead of the symbols used in wildcards?

Time, such as `9:54` or `10:23` with or without `am`, `a.m.`, `AM`, `A.M.`, `pm`, `p.m.`, `PM`, `P.M.`:

```
\d{1,2}[:]\d{2}\ ?([aAPp].?[Mm].?)?
```

I want to transform the above regular expression to be compatible with a wildcard search in Outlook. So when I create find and replace macro I can use that wildcard expression to capture that string and format it to whatever I want.

Comment: There's no `*` in the regexp, what isn't working?

Comment: You need to escape `.`. You don't have to escape space. You don't have to put `:` inside `[]`.

Comment: The question isn't clear -- do you want to fix the regexp, or do you want a wildcard? Wildcards aren't as expressive as regexp, they don't have things like "optional AM/PM"

Comment: I deleted my answer and put your clarification of what it is that you want in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *match pattern*.  This will also match *"Am"*, *"pM"*, etc.

```
(?i)\d\d?:\d\d(?: (?:[ap]\.?m\.?))?
```

- `(?i)`, toggle on *"case-insensitive"* mode
- `\d\d?`, match any digit, optionally succeeded by another digit
- `:`, match a literal `:` character
- `\d\d`, match any 2 consecutive digits
- `(?: (?:[ap]\.?m\.?))?`, match an optional, succeeding static text, "a.m.", "pm", etc.

Or, to match only hours and minutes, specify each value.
This is the same as above, except the `\d\d?:\d\d` pattern is defined.

```
(?i)(?:[1-9]|1[0-2]):(?:[0-5]\d)(?: (?:[ap]\.?m\.?))?
```

Comment: I put these match patterns inside find and replace in Outlook and no results were found. I don't think these are formatted for wildcard. Only Regular Expressions

Comment: @churchizactiive, try `#*[:]##[ aApPmM.]*`, the final `*` might not be needed.  I'm referencing the following, _https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/examples-of-wildcard-characters-939e153f-bd30-47e4-a763-61897c87b3f4_.

Comment: @Reilas `\.?`  would match a literal backslash followed by a literal `.` followed by any character according to the documentation you linked to. There doesn't seem to be any support for any of the other regex constructs you're using either.